# How to use dynamic class values like disabled or active with theme-ui?

Tags: reactjs, theme-ui, rebass

So, I am using theme-ui and its theming capabilities, but i am new at it.

In my old way, I would just use package classNames and dynamically add styles depending on props or state etc..

ala...

```
        const btnStyles = cn('plainButton', {
          [styles.active]: isActive,
          [styles.disabled]: isDisabled,
        });
```

So, as you can see - I could update the button based on props. How would i do this wit theme-ui?

How do I had a dynamic disabled or say "active" state to a button or div or whatever using theme-ui. How do I achieve that? Would i have to declare a theme type in my theme.js file, or us "jx" to override?

Any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the style of disabled and active state in `theme.buttons` object :

```
// example theme variants
{
 buttons: {
   primary: {
     color: 'background',
     bg: 'primary',
     '&:disabled': {
       //your style
     },
     '&:active': {
       //your style
     }
   }
 }
}
```

For [more](https://theme-ui.com/components/button/)

Comment: Right, ok, this makes sense. But how would I add "active" or "disabled" onto my Theme-ui components? I might have missed it, but does it take "className" or ?

Comment: You don't need to pass the className. For example, when your button is disabled you can do this <Button disabled={disabled}>Beep</Button>, so the button will be rendered with a disabled style defined in the theme.buttons.

Comment: same for "active", it's mapped w/prop ie.. <Button active={active} etc...?

Comment: You don't need to do it for the active state.

Comment: Then how do I know if a compent has that "active" class? How do I dynamically add that do the component? with className?

Comment: You don't need that, CSS can automatically detect if the button is in an active state or not. You have only to put your style inside theme.buttons object with the pseudo-class active.